# How to set up a specific preloader

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set up a preloader like the one on this site: https://www.freche-associes.fr.
I think that with the code below I am not far from the result, but I need the ideas to move forward
Thank you in advance.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#preloader").delay(1000).slideUp("slow"); 
  $(".text1").delay(900).fadeOut("slow"); 
  $(".line").delay(700).fadeOut("slow"); 
  $(".text2").delay(500).fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

```css
section{
  height: 500px;
  
}
#preloader{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%
}
.line{
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="preloader">
        <h2 class="text1">My Consulting</h2>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3 class="text2">The best of...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">All description!!!</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is a place for _specific_ questions about problems with code you have written. _“I need the ideas to move forward”_ is anything but that.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.addEventListener`

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        $("#preloader").delay(1000).slideUp("slow");
        $(".text1").delay(900).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".line").delay(700).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".text2").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
    })
```

```css
       section{
            height: 500px;

        }
        #preloader{
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%
        }
        .line{
            width:150px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div id="preloader">
        <h2 class="text1">My Consulting</h2>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3 class="text2">The best of...</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">All description!!!</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. I change something to to have just about what I want. Just "All description!!!" remains fixed at the top. But it's ok

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       
        $(".text1").delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".line").delay(1000).animate({width: '150px'}, "slow");
        $(".text2").delay(1800).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#preloader").delay(2500).animate({top: '0px'});
    })
```

```css
section{
            height: 500px;
            width:500px

        }
        .container{
          width: 100%;
            background-color:gray;
        }
        #preloader{
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            height: 100px
        }
        .line{
            width:0px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="preloader">
        <h2 class="text1" style="display:none">My Consulting</h2>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3 class="text2" style="display:none">The best of...</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">All description!!!</div>
</section>
```